# Clickable TextView to OnClickListener Action_Dial kills app

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, clickable

I am taking a class in Mobile App Development and we are designing an app to build a ticket system.  On the main activity - we will have five clickable buttons as well as a clickable text which when clicked on takes you to the dial page with the number 9999999999 already placed in the dial box.  In the layout - I have set customerCare TextView to clickable = "true".  Everytime I click on the link in genny motion - it kills the app.  I have tried finding resources online, but all code seems to match mine.  I have tried both Action_Call as well as Action_Dial.  Any help would be greatly appreciated... I am assuming it is a small fix.  Thank you in advance.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView makeCall = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_care);
        //makeCall.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        findViewById(R.id.btnCreateTicket).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateTicket.class);
                //Intent intent = new Intent("com.bignerdranch.android.intents.action.View");
                //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

                //intent.putExtra(NAME_KEY, "Bob Smith");
                //intent.putExtra(AGE_KEY, (double) 25.5);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        makeCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel" + "999 999 9999"));

                startActivity(callIntent);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `"tel" + "999 999 9999"` You're missing a colon (`:`) after `tel`. Voting to close as this is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check if emulator have the application to handle this sort of intent?

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }   else  {
            Log.d(TAG, "No Intent available to handle action");
        }
```